# How to create Google Plus like Lightbox/Modalbox

Tags: php, modal-dialog, lightbox, effect, google-plus

Facebook Lightbox/Modalbox has been very popular and I found the Google Plus modal box very attractive and useful to use on my website
Can anyone tell me how to create Google Plus Lightbox/Modal-box
atleast let me know the idea to create such effect

Especially I am more interested in the draggable feature of modalbox of google plus

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just realized that I kind of assumed you were using ASP.  Are you using ASP on your website, or something else?

Comment: I've added the PHP tag and removed my answer (since it was ASP.NET-specific).  Hopefully someone else can help you out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use lightbox and then redesign the HTML of that lightbox and then you have to use the jQuery UI to make that draggable.

In details:

For the design please check the jQuery lightbox and change the HTML of the function `_set_interface()` function.

And to make that dragable you can use http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/.

Comment: In this case, better use jQueryUI Dialog http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog, it support jqueryUI themes